# PHP doesnt validate accordingly

Tags: php, html, css

I set up a HTML Contact form which forwards the data to a php script which then sends an email to a specified account.

Somehow the VALIDATE_MAIL filter doesnt work and I'm unable to see where the mistake is... Can someone of you help me?

Heres the HTML-Code:

```
<form method="post" action="send_email.php">
<h3>Kontaktieren Sie uns</h3>
<input type=text id=name name=name placeholder=Name>
<input type=text id=organisation name=organisation placeholder=Organisation>
<input type=text id=Email name=Email placeholder=Email>
<input type=text id=betreff name=betreff placeholder=Betreff>
<textarea type=text id=subject name=subject placeholder=Nachricht style=height:200px></textarea>
<div class=g-recaptcha data-sitekey=6Lf1GGsUAAAAAJJTsKuFXZkO6UPhfCspnOmInRlS style="transform:scale(0.85);-webkit-transform:scale(0.85);transform-origin:0 0;-webkit-transform-origin:0 0"></div>
<input type=submit value="Nachricht senden">
<div id=info onclick=change()>Kontaktinformation</div>
</form>
```

And here is the PHP Code:

```
<?php
//send_email.php
$email_from = "Absender";   //Absender falls keiner angegeben wurde
$sendermail_antwort = true;      //E-Mail Adresse des Besuchers als Absender. false= Nein ; true = Ja
$name_von_emailfeld = "Email";   //Feld in der die Absenderadresse steht

$empfaenger = "info@drupe.ch"; //Empfänger-Adresse
$mail_cc = ""; //CC-Adresse, diese E-Mail-Adresse bekommt einer weitere Kopie
$betreff = "Neue Kontaktanfrage"; //Betreff der Email

$url_ok = "http://www.drupe.ch/contactsuccess.html"; //Zielseite, wenn E-Mail erfolgreich versendet wurde
$url_fehler = "http://www.drupe.ch/error.html"; //Zielseite, wenn E-Mail nicht gesendet werden konnte


//Diese Felder werden nicht in der Mail stehen
$ignore_fields = array('submit');




//Datum, wann die Mail erstellt wurde
$name_tag = array("Sonntag", "Montag", "Dienstag", "Mittwoch", "Donnerstag", "Freitag", "Samstag");
$num_tag = date("w");
$tag = $name_tag[$num_tag];
$jahr = date("Y");
$n = date("d");
$monat = date("m");
$time = date("H:i");

//Erste Zeile unserer Email
$msg = ":: Gesendet am $tag, den $n.$monat.$jahr - $time Uhr ::\n\n";

//Hier werden alle Eingabefelder abgefragt
foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
   if (in_array($name, $ignore_fields)) {
        continue; //Ignore Felder wird nicht in die Mail eingefügt
   }
   $msg .= "::: $name :::\n$value\n\n";
}


$a = "@";
//E-Mail Adresse des Besuchers als Absender
if ($sendermail_antwort and isset($_POST[$name_von_emailfeld]) and filter_var($_POST[$name_von_emailfeld], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
   $email_from = $_POST[$name_von_emailfeld];
}

$header="From: $email_from";

if (!empty($mail_cc)) {
   $header .= "\n";
   $header .= "Cc: $mail_cc";
}



//Email als UTF-8 senden
$header .= "\nContent-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8";

$mail_senden = mail($empfaenger,$betreff,$msg,$header);


//Weiterleitung, hier konnte jetzt per echo auch Ausgaben stehen
if($mail_senden){
  header("Location: ".$url_ok); //Mail wurde gesendet
  exit();
} else{
  header("Location: ".$url_fehler); //Fehler beim Senden
  exit();
}
```

The email does get sent. So everything works about it but only the filter doesnt work. What am I doing wrong? If any of you could point me to the right direction that would be really helpful.

Thanks alot in advance :)

Comment: Could it be that the domain in the email address contains non-latin characters?

Comment: Describe "doesn't work". What is the validation doing? Can you provide an example so we can test?

Comment: Can you show us the email that is failing or does it always fail

Comment: `var_dump($_POST[$name_von_emailfeld])` gives what? Did you put an `else` on the conditional to confirm it is false?

Comment: Your `if`-statement works just fine for a proper email address: https://3v4l.org/CeHcF - Without knowing what email address you're testing with, we have no clue what's going on.

Comment: I wonder, as I am prone to do, if this isn't a UTF-8 issue...all the way through.

Comment: What does this have to do with CSS.

Comment: "Doesnt work" means, if i enter somethinglike namelastname.com I would expect the php script to forward me to the error.html page but it doesnt. It forwards me towards the "success" page and it also sends the email to my defined emailadress (info@drupe.ch) which it shouldnt do aswell.    And yeah it has nothing to do with CSS - im sorry for using the wrong tags.

Comment: The only thing that your code does _not_ do if the `$_POST[$name_von_emailfeld]` value is invalid is that it doesn't set the `$email_from` variable.  Everything else still happens.  So I'm not sure why you expect the above-stated result.

Comment: @Patrick q what would I have to do/change in the php that it forwards me towards the error.html  if the mailadress is invalid? I'm not that good in php so sorry for anything that seems like a dumb question

Comment: Put basically all the code that comes after your current `if` check to be _within_ the body of that check.  Then add an `else` that does whatever you want (send to an error page, for example)

Comment: @PatrickQ I got an idea which looked easier for me, my idea was to simply search through the email with strpos if theres an @ inside. Which I guess should work aswell?
Would that work this way?:
`if ($sendermail_antwort and isset($_POST[$name_von_emailfeld]) and filter_var($_POST[$name_von_emailfeld], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) and (strpos($name_von_emailfeld, "@") !== false) {
   $email_from = $_POST[$name_von_emailfeld];
}
else {
  header('Location: http://www.drupe.ch/error.html'); 
}`

Answer (score 0):

According to [php.net manual](http://php.net/manual/de/function.filter-var.php) the `filter_var` returns the filtered value on success and `false` in a case of an error.

So maybe the `filter_var` part should be sth. like:

```
filter_var($_POST[$name_von_emailfeld], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false
```

to be valid in the if-clause.

Of course you should handle the else-case as well, to not send the email if the email address is not valid.

Comment: The returned email address would by considered a "truthy" value

Comment: @Patrick Q, yes of course you're right, but I prefer this way to make it more readable. In the owners issue, here should have definitly the "else"-case to check whats going wrong.

Comment: It might be cleaner but unfortunately, it's not a solution (which answers should be) to the OP's issue (which we still haven't gotten a clarification about)

Comment: Ok, mea culpa! I hope you'll be forgiving me this first mistake.